# How to use/do coding on a same web application between two people

Tags: svn, version-control

We are a two man team working on a same c#, .net web application. Now everytime we do anything we have to merge our files. Also we can not work on same files together. We know we can use a source safe so that we can work together on the same project at a time but not sure how to use it on our desktop pc (we do not have a server where we can put our code). Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Git is helpful and keeps track of changes
See more on http://www.git-scm.com/

Comment: I don't have a server computer so what would be the steps?

Comment: For git, you can host server on one of working computers, or use some git hosting (examples - github for open, bitbucket for private)

Comment: the question is how? I have windows 7 installed on my desktop so how do I make my machine as server so that I can share just one application on which we both can work together

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide